# Volatility and thread safety in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition, volatile

please take this very simple example:

```
volatile int globalVar = 1;
```

My thread:

```
if (globalVar > 0) {
    globalVar--;
}
```

Now, I have to decide whether making the variable volatile is sufficient to prevent a race-condition and make this thread safe.

I know incrementing and decrementing is not, but I'm not sure if it's different, because of the preceding condition.

I think it still is not safe, because it could be executed in this order:

Thread A checks condition. Thread B checks condition.
Thread A increments. Thread B increments.

Am I right?

Comment: That's not the only reason; decrementing alone is not thread-safe.

Comment: You need to think of `globalVar--` as the thread loading globalVar, subtracting one from the result, and writing the new value to globalVar, three separate operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is NOT thread safe for the reason you state. `volatile` ensures that two threads will both see updated values of a variable but is does not protect around multiple lines of code.

Comment: It doesn't even protect single lines of code - the `globalVar--` is _not_ atomic.

Comment: Which the OP highlighed: `I know incrementing and decrementing is not`

Answer (score 1):

No its not Thread safe.
Volatile doesn't guarantee Atomicity. Operations like 
i-- are not atomic so declaring i as volatile doesn't help.

```
int globalVar = 1;

lock.lock()
try{
  if(globalVar > 0)
          globalVar--;

}finally {
   lock.unlock();
}
```

The above code will work, you don't need to declare golbalVar as volatile here
because
Volatile Gives Two Guarantees:
1. Visibility
2. Reordering

Whereas

Synchronization/lock/unlock Give Three guarantees
1.Atomicity
2. Visibility
3.Reordering

Also Remember whenever an Object is shared among multiple threads always access that 
object under any synchronization action synchronization/volatile read/write.

Read an Excellent Article here by the Author Chapter 17 of JLS. Its a must read
http://jeremymanson.blogspot.in/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html

Answer (score 0):

To make your code thread safe you need to add a `synchronized` block around the check and modification.

An example of what can be done:

```
volatile Integer globalVar = 1;
```

Then in the method that does the work you can:

```
synchronized public void decrement(){
    if(globalVar > 0)
          globalVar--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work.  globalVar is immutable, so the modifications to it will create a new object, which means different threads will be locking on different objects.  This is why you should normally synchronize on final references.

Answer (score 0):

volatile does not guarantees for Atomicity. you can simply add a synchronized block.

```
synchronized(this)
{
 if (globalVar > 0) {
   globalVar--;
 }
}
```